# Data is clearing when I click route page About in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Help me please! I have two pages: `Home`, `About` and a component `SecondPage`. This component has two tables with data, and it should be displayed on `About` page. But when I navigate to `About` page, all data is cleared, and tables are empty. 
I tried to display all from `About` page as `About` component in my main page `Home`, and it works! So, props are passed correctly.
Why all data from tables disappearing in `About` page when I click it? 
I tried `.prevent`, but it doesn't work as I expect.

About.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
     <SecondPage v-bind:generalQuestInfo="generalQuestInfo" :isActive="isActive" :getIconClass="getIconClass" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SecondPage from '../components/SecondPage'


export default {
  name: 'About',
  components: {
    SecondPage 
  },
  props: ["generalQuestInfo", "isActive", "getIconClass"]    
  }

  </script>
```

Home

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Quest Statistics</h1> 
    <MainPage v-bind:mainPageInfo="mainPageInfo" v-on:main-handle="handler(loadGeneralQuestInfo, loadFinishedQuestleafs, $event)" />    
     <SecondPage v-bind:generalQuestInfo="generalQuestInfo" :isActive="isActive" :getIconClass="getIconClass"/>
     <About v-bind:generalQuestInfo="generalQuestInfo" :isActive="isActive" :getIconClass="getIconClass"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import MainPage from '../components/MainPage'
import SecondPage from '../components/SecondPage'
import About from './About'
import axios from 'axios'


export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    MainPage,
    SecondPage,
    About      
  },

  data(){
  return {
    mainPageInfo: [],
      generalQuestInfo: [],
      finishedQuestleafs: [],
    isActive: 0             //this value is changing according to icon that was clicked in table from MainTable.vue
  }
},
```

SecondPage

```
<template>
    <div>
        //two tables are here
   </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: "SecondPage",
    props: ["generalQuestInfo", "isActive", "getIconClass"]     

}
```

Adding another piece of code. When click on icon, it suppose to open `About` page with tables. But tables are empty, it looks like redirecting happens before props are passed to child component??? Page is not reloading

MainPage

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
              <th v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in mainPageInfo">{{ data.alias }}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>        
                <td v-bind:key="data.id" v-for="data in mainPageInfo">          
                    <router-link :to="data.status == 'SUCCESS' || data.status == 'CRASH' ? '/about' : '/no-info'"><i v-on:click="$emit('main-handle', data.status)" v-bind:class="data.status == 'SUCCESS' ? 'fas fa-check': 
                        data.status == 'CRASH' ? 'fas fa-times' : 
                                      'fas fa-minus'"></i></router-link>        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please provide `SecondPage.vue` and Home

Comment: also you should be getting this error `<Secondpage > - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.` and its because you are using Capital case letter  ... you need to change `<SecondPage >` to `<Second-page >`

Comment: I added a code. Where exactly name should be like <Second-page >?

Comment: @Dadboz in Vue it's perfectly valid to use capital letters in components. Check their documentation for multiple examples: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/

Comment: @Joseph im not talking about the first letter of the component ... a letter that comes in the middle (after the first one) ... you can try that and see if doesn't throw an error

Comment: it doesn't throw an error either I use ```SecondPage``` or ```Second-page```. It works the same.

Comment: @Dadboz Again, please look at the link I posted. Pascal-case is perfectly valid unless you're using a DOM template - i.e. loading from a .HTML file. I did try the code above, along with every piece of Vue code I've ever written, and all of them work fine with Pascal case :p

Comment: @Yuril, you're correct - using Pascal case (UpperLetter) is fine as long as you're within a .Vue file.

Comment: thanks, but that is not a problem I mentioned in the post)

Comment: Joseph I added one more peace of code, please look at!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `store` with `Vuex`, and this problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

Vue documentation indicates [Prop Casing (camelCase vs kebab-case)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:

Then when u call some component in his HTML template you should write the prop in kebab-case:

```
<!-- kebab-case in HTML -->
<blog-post post-title="hello!"></blog-post>
```

And on your component u must to call your props in camelCase:

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['postTitle'],
  template: '<h3>{{ postTitle }}</h3>'
})
```

Comment: So, how can this affect to my code? I don't see errors, just data not displaying on ```About``` page...